# App Engine sample program on Windows 10 tries to run under the wrong GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Working in nodejs-docs-samples on Windows 10 machine. Tried to follow ... /nodejs-docs-samples/datastore/README.md to run the Datastore sample app in App Engine Standard environment, and when I go to localhost:8080, I get this:

```
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: The project <my-deleted-datastore-project> does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database.
```

I have set up a new project that uses Firestore in Datastore mode. How do I

1. **track down and delete references to the deleted project** -- in other words, where are they referenced? I have looked through .json and .yaml files and system and user environment variables; nothing there.
2. point the App Engine sample code to the new, correct GCP project?

The new project is set in the GCP Console as my default project, but that doesn't fix it. As for authentication, etc., I'm trying to keep that as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check a few things:

1. Did you enable Datastore API? If not, enable it [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=datastore.googleapis.com&redirect=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/datastore).
2. Does your new project have an active application? You can activate your application by going to app Engine in your console and click on 'Create Application'. did you set your new project as active project? Use `gcloud congif set project [PROJECT_ID]` to set it right, then you can verify it using this: `gcloud info | grep Project`.
3. Also, I believe [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial) explains what you are looking for